# HBase REST: declare a coprocessor

Tags: hbase, stargate

I am having difficulties in creating an HBase table with a co-processor via HBase REST.

**hbase_table_ttt.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<TableSchema name="ttt" coprocessor="hdfs:///my_coprocessor-1.0.jar|com.mycompany.MyCoprocessor|1001|">
    <ColumnSchema name="d" BLOCKCACHE="true" VERSIONS="1" IN_MEMORY="true"/>
</TableSchema>
```

with a follow-up call to create a table:

```
TARGET_HOST="hbase-instance-with-rest.amazonaws.com:8080"
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "Accept: text/xml" -d @hbase_table_ttt.xml http://$TARGET_HOST/ttt/schema/
```

results in a following schema, with disabled coprocessor:

```
'ttt', {METHOD => 'table_att', CONFIG => {'coprocessor' => 'hdfs:///my_coprocessor-1.0.jar|com.mycompany.MyCoprocessor|1001|'}}, 
       {NAME => 'd', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', 
        MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => '2147483647', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'false', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', 
        IN_MEMORY => 'true', ENCODE_ON_DISK => 'true', BLOCKCACHE=>'true'}
```

at the same time, `hbase shell` commands:

```
create 'ttt', 'd'
disable 'ttt'
alter 'ttt', METHOD => 'table_att', 'coprocessor'=>'hdfs:///my_coprocessor-1.0.jar|com.mycompany.MyCoprocessor|1001|'
enable 'ttt'
```

results in a schema with enabled co-processor:

```
'ttt', {METHOD => 'table_att', coprocessor$1 => 'hdfs:///my_coprocessor-1.0.jar|com.mycompany.MyCoprocessor|1001|'}, 
       {NAME => 'd', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'NONE',
        MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => '2147483647', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'false', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', 
        IN_MEMORY => 'true', ENCODE_ON_DISK => 'true', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
```

Question:

- How can I properly register a coprocessor within the **hbase_table_ttt.xml** file?